# Biggest non-contiguous submatrix with all ones

Tags: algorithm, matrix, optimization, boolean, linear-programming

I'm tackling the problem of finding a non-contiguous submatrix of a boolean matrix with maximum size such that all of its cells are ones.

As an example, consider the following matrix:

```
M = [[1, 0, 1, 1],
     [0, 0, 1, 0],
     [1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

A non-contiguous submatrix of M is specified as a set of rows R and a set of columns C. The submatrix is formed by all the cells that are in some row in R **and** in some column in C (the intersections of R and C). Note that a non-contiguous submatrix is a generalization of a submatrix, so any (contiguous) submatrix is also a non-contiguous submatrix.

There is one maximum non-contiguous submatrix of M that has a one in all of its cells. This submatrix is defined as R={1, 3, 4} and C={1, 3}, which yields:

```
M[1, 2, 4][1, 3] = [[1, 1, 1],
                    [1, 1, 1]]
```

I'm having difficulties finding existing literature about this problem. I'm looking for efficient algorithms that don't necessarily need to be optimal (so I can relax the problem to finding maximal size submatrices). Of course, this can be modeled with integer linear programming, but I want to consider other alternatives.

In particular, I want to know if this problem is already known and covered by the literature, and I want to know if my definition of non-contiguous matrix makes sense and whether already exists a different name for them.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the maximum matrix size that you are considering? Do you have a particular time limit?

Comment: The matrix will be of the order of 50x50, although I'm also interested in efficient algorithms for the general case. The time limit should be around 0.1 seconds although I'm flexible with that

Comment: It's the maximum edge biclique problem, NP-hard. Posting as a comment because I don't have an algorithm suggestion for you offhand.

Comment: I've heard of this kind of submatrix as "rectangle". I came across it in the context of the "Rectangle Covering Number". Maybe that makes finding literature easier. (I'd look in the context of "Rectangle Covering Number")

Comment: Thanks a lot @DavidEisenstat! I'm not necessarily looking for an algorithm, since knowing that the problem is NP-hard allows me to focus on heuristics and greedy algorithms. So if you post this comment as an answer I will accept it. I've also found https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/190162/finding-the-largest-rectangular-submatrix which you can link in your answer too. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @JosefWittmann Actually, the underlying problem that I want to solve is precisely the Rectangle Covering Number. I didn't know of its existence so thank you very very much, it's super helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since per your response to Josef Wittmann's comment you want to find the Rectangle Covering Number, my suggestion would be to construct the Lovász–Saks graph and apply a graph coloring algorithm.

The Lovász–Saks graph has a vertex for each 1 entry in the matrix and an edge between each pair of vertices whose 2x2 matrix contains a zero. In your example,

```
[[1, 0, 1, 1],
 [0, 0, 1, 0],
 [1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

we can label the 1s with letters:

```
[[a, 0, b, c],
 [0, 0, d, 0],
 [e, f, g, h]]
```

and then get edges

```
a--d, a--f, b--f, c--d, c--f, d--e, d--f, d--h.

a b   a 0   0 b   b c   0 c   0 d   0 d   d 0
0 d   e f   f g   d 0   f h   e f   f g   g h
```

I think an optimal coloring is

```
{a, b, c, e, g, h} -> 1
{d} -> 2
{f} -> 3.
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm wondering if greedily finding the largest 1-rectangle iteratively until all the 1s are covered leads to the Rectangle Covering Number. i.e., If we find the largest 1-rectangle and change the ones to zeros, repeating this process until no ones are left, the number of iterations is equal to the Rectangle Covering Number. My guess is that this is true, although I haven't found a proof.

Comment: Nevermind, this is not true since I found a counter-example:
[[1 1 0],
 [1 1 1],
 [0 1 1]]

Comment: Well, I still would like to know if that procedure would yield the non-overlapping 1-rectangle cover with less rectangles possible (not the Rectangle Covering Number since overlaps of rectangles are not allowed)

Comment: Nevermind, I answered myself finding a (non-trivial) counterexample :)

Comment: @GonzaloSolera you might be able to enumerate all bicliques and then either use a greedy strategy or write out the exact cover integer program.

Answer (score 0):

I have been investigating this issue in the case of matrices containing missing data (NaN) and wanted to address the question "which samples and features should be removed to retain the matrix with the largest number of elements." I developed a heuristic that involves searching for permutations of rows and columns that "organize" the cells with NaN (or zero in your case) as much as possible in the bottom-left corner of the matrix. Then, I calculate the largest rectangle (contiguous this time) without NaN starting from the upper-right corner of the matrix. This information, with a variation of two permutations, guides us on the set of columns and rows to be removed from the original matrix.

For example, if this is the matrix to be processed:

[image: matrix to be processed]

Then, a series of permutations (columns and rows) is calculated, based on sorting the indices of NaN elements furthest to the right or highest:

[image: iteration]

[image: iteration2]

[image: iteration3]

And the largest **contiguous** rectangle without NaN can be computed, giving us the rows and columns to be removed.

I have created a python package named [optimask](https://github.com/CyrilJl/OptiMask) that encapsulates this algorithm. It is heuristic, but efficient and can be useful.

Here's the exemple of a 50x50 matrix with NaNs processed by optimask: in grey are the NaN cells, in red the removed columns and rows, in blue the computed submatrix:

[image: result]